# Textblock loses boldness of bold text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I have a `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TopTextBlock">
   Normals words followed by <Bold>Bold words</Bold>
</Textblock>
```

It displays the text bold.

However, if in my C# code I make any alterations to the string such as

```
TopTextBlock.Text += " word"
```

The text will no longer appear bold

Comment: You have to make it in code behind as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add string in TextBlock Inlines instead of setting Text DP :

```
TopTextBlock.Inlines.Add(" word");
```

Or in case want to add Bold text :

```
TopTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(" word") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
```

Answer (score 1):

The XAML implicitly sets the TextBlock's `Inlines` property, whereas in code behind you set the `Text` property. You might however add text to the Inlines collection like this:

```
TopTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(" word"));
```

or shorter:

```
TopTextBlock.Inlines.Add(" word");
```